# How to format a string like 2014-09-27 00:00:00 +0000 in date in ios 7?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have string like;

```
NSString *str = @"2014-09-27 00:00:00 +0000";
```

I want to convert it into date.
plz help me..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Seriously?  You can't search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check here [Convert date from string](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-3.html)
or you can use this methods to convert

```
-(NSString*)getStringFromDate:(NSDate*)pDate withFormat:(NSString*)pDateFormat{
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:pDateFormat];
[dtFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
return [dtFormatter stringFromDate:pDate];}

-(NSDate*)getDateFromString:(NSString*)pStrDate withFormat:(NSString*)pDateFormat{
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:pDateFormat];
[dtFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
return [dtFormatter dateFromString:pStrDate];}

-(NSString*)dateStringFromString:(NSString *)dateToConver format:(NSString *)fromFormat toFormat:(NSString *)toFormat{
NSDate *date = [Helper getDateFromString:dateToConver withFormat:fromFormat];
return [Helper getStringFromDate:date withFormat:toFormat];}
```